# Udacity Corrector CS253 give me errors

Tags: python, http, redirect

I'm trying to pass the Final Exam on CS253 in Udacity (Web Development with Python), but I got this error.

```
We received status code 200 in your HTTP Response when trying to post to the page      
http://donadevwiki.appspot.com/_edit/PVftJYpwWboj

After editing, we should be redirected to http://donadevwiki.appspot.com/PVftJYpwWboj      
indicated by status code 302.
```

My webapp works fine, and I don't know where I'm wrong..
Somebody can help me?

Firstable, i had this Handler:

```
class EditPage(Handler):
    def get(self,name): 
        query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM WikiDB WHERE link=:1",name).get()
        content = ""
        if checkUser(self) is None:
            self.redirect("/login")
        if query is not None:
            content = query.content
        self.render("edit.html",content=content,username=checkUser(self),wiki=name)
```

but when i see the corrector error (that was similar to this, but had an http 405 error instead the 200 error), i changed to

```
 class EditPage(Handler):
    def get(self,name): 
        query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM WikiDB WHERE link=:1",name).get()
        content = ""
        if checkUser(self) is None:
            self.redirect("/login")
        if query is not None:
            content = query.content
        self.render("edit.html",content=content,username=checkUser(self),wiki=name) 
    def post(self,name): 
        query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM WikiDB WHERE link=:1",name).get()
        content = ""
        if checkUser(self) is None:
            self.redirect("/login")
        if query is not None:
            content = query.content
        self.render("edit.html",content=content,username=checkUser(self),wiki=name)
```

and the corrector gave me this error. I know that both post and get method do the same thing, but i do the post method only for testing the corrector :-)

```
 def checkUser(self):
    cookie = self.request.cookies.get('user_id')
    if cookie:
        val = check_secure_val(cookie)
        if val:
            dictio = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM User").fetch(limit=32423)
            for user in dictio:
                if user.key().id()==int(val):
                    return user.name
```

Comment: Please add your source code. Probably you do not return a 302 http response, according to the message you received, but a plain http 200 page. I suppose there is an error in the logic of your code not returning the correct redirect.

Comment: i've done it. Hope you can help me..

Comment: You definitely need to understand what http response codes are. Please read http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes and you'll get an idea of the reasons why you received the 405 error and why 200 is a message of success, not an error. However the exam require you to terminate your function with a redirect after you validate/save the input received by a POST request

Comment: You are welcome, good luck for your exam!